# Under which assumptions is $\hat{x}_{MMSE}=E[x|y]$?

Tags: estimation, mse

I've allways used MMSE estimators starting from the expected value of the conditional distribution $E[x|y]$ and I saw in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_square_error#Properties) that there were

> some weak regularity assumptions

for this equality to be considered true. I looked up Corollary 4.1.2 from Lehmann and Casella [Theory of point estimation](http://amarestan.com/images/docs/files/000000/nf00000060-1.pdf) as mentioned in the Wikipedia reference but I just couldn't find it.

Any explanation about these "assumptions" would be of much help.
Thanks.